# How to refactor this POST code from MySQL to PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, pg-promise

I have this todo_list app built using:

- Node.js
- Express.js
- EJS
- MySQL

Choosing a database by following instructions from this Express website:
https://expressjs.com/en/guide/database-integration.html#mysql
https://expressjs.com/en/guide/database-integration.html#postgresql

I managed to make MySQL work with my todo_list app. But I'm having trouble refactoring the same **CRUD (create)** code for PostgreSQL use. Below is the working MySQL CRUD code and the unfinished PostgreSQL CRUD code for comparison. What am I doing wrong?

**MySQL CRUD (create) code** = works!

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

const app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.static("public"));

// _____________________________________________________________________________
// Add new list item - MySQL

let mysql = require('mysql');

let connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: 'localhost',
  user: 'dbuser1',
  password: '12345',
  database: 'testdb1',
});


app.post("/", function(req, res) {

  const itemName = req.body.newItem;
  let data = { name: itemName };
  let sql = "INSERT INTO `todo_list` SET ?";

  let query = connection.query(sql, data, function(err, results) {
    if (err) throw err;
    res.redirect('/');
  });

});
```

**PostgreSQL CRUD (create) code** = doesn't work!

```
// .............................................................................
// Add new list item - PostgreSQL

// Loading and initializing the library without Initialization Options.
const pgp = require('pg-promise')();

const connection = {
  user     : 'pig1',
  password : '12345',
  host     : 'localhost',
  port     : '5432',
  database : 'todo_list'
};

// Database instance
const db = pgp(connection);


app.post("/", function(req, res) {

  const itemName = req.body.newItem;
  let data = { name: itemName };
  let sql = "INSERT INTO todo_list SET ?";

  db.any(sql, data)
  .then(results => {
    console.log(`Inserted data into database!`);
    console.log('DATA:', results);

    res.redirect('/');
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log('ERROR:', error);
  })
  .finally(db.$pool.end);
});
```

Comment: What you do wrong.... 1) PostgreSQL does not support `?` for variable values, it is not MySQL. Check [the driver for correct variable placeholders syntax](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise#query-formatting). 2) You should not destroy connection pool after each API call, i.e. remove that `.finally(db.$pool.end);`. 3) You are misusing StackOverflow, without reading its question guidelines about how to ask questions: You did not even state the nature of the problem or what you tried to resolve it, and evidently without any due research.

Comment: Try something like:

let data = { name: itemName }; 
await db.query('INSERT INTO todo_list(${this:name}) VALUES (${this:csv})', data)


Where todo_list table has a column "name" and with same type as itemName.

Folowing this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/pg-promise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the pointers! @vitaly-t @rabhi-salim

I managed to make the CRUD (create) code work with **PostgreSQL** now.

```js
app.post("/", function(req, res) {

  const itemName = req.body.newItem;
  let data = { name: itemName };

  async function askStackOverflow() {
    try {
          await db.none('INSERT INTO todo_list(${this:name}) VALUES (${this:csv})', data);

          // --- SUCCESS ---
          console.log(``);
          console.log(`Inserted data into database!`);
          console.log(`DATA:`, insertedItem);

          res.redirect('/');
    } catch(error) {
         // --- ERROR ---
         console.log('ERROR:', error);
    }
  }

  (async () => {
    await askStackOverflow();
  })();

});
```

**Extra reading material:**

Promises, Callback Hell, Async Await (ES7)
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/javascript-promises-for-dummies

https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise/wiki/Learn-by-Example#insert-with-result

https://www.npmjs.com/package/pg-promise#named-parameters

Comment: Amended: 1) Use method `none` when your query isn't expected to return anything 2) Do not try get value from something that isn't supposed to return any. 3) Enumerate column names automatically, using `:name` filter.